# How to loop php json encoded array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, loops

I get below result when I echo php **json_encode** function

```
 [Object { item_id="18", name="Chocolate Cherry"}, Object { item_id="19", name="Spicy Mango "}]
```

How can loop through it?

Comment: It is a string now, decode to loop through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, simple javascript no jquery

```js
var json = [{
    "id" : "18", 
    "name"   : "Chocolate Cherry"
},
{
    "id" : "19", 
    "name"   : "Spicy Mango"
}];

for (var key in json) {
       if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          alert(json[key].id);
          alert(json[key].name);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.parseJSON() would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your json string is str_json,
At first parse it, using JSON.parse, after that you can loop it.

```
var arr_json = JSON.parse( str_json );
for( index in arr_json) {
    alert( arr_json[index] )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out.

```
jsonobj = 'Your Json Object';    
var jsontoarr = JSON.parse(jsonobj);
    for( jsontoarr_each in jsontoarr) {
       console.log(jsontoarr_each.item_id);
       console.log(jsontoarr_each.name);
    }
```

Will loop through the values.